# Can I point a example.com/subdirectory to another IP address?

Tags: dns

I have 2 servers and 1 domain name. Is there a way to point the domain at server 1 but then point `example.com/subdirectory` to server 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because domain translation is done before the request of the resource. The resource is your path `/subdirectory`. The domain-translation is `example.com`.

You can use redirection to redirect to an other domain if someone access `example.com/directory` to `directory.example.com` and map this domain to an other IP.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind using a sub-domain, this is possible. You can redirect the directory to the sub-domain.

Otherwise, if you have your own network or your host can host a proxy server you would be able to proxy any request to any server however you like. It has been 12 years since I have done this, but we operated several proxy servers including reverse proxies that allowed us to create many URLs that appeared to exist on one domain and point them to many servers and implement a form of load balancing. As well, some services we offered were on different operating systems, application platforms, portals, CMS, application servers, and so on. Using proxies allowed about 200 servers to appear as one verbose website.

You do not have to get this complicated of course. But this is something you can look at for your needs. Research using Apache. Apache can do what you want and this is something your host should be able host easily or implement on your own network for a decent price. Also keep in mind that there are proxy servers both software and hardware that offer options. Apache is free however and works extremely well. Just be careful of the configuration or you will get 100,000+ proxy bounces from China per hour within seconds. But do not let that scare you! Just be thorough in your work and you should be fine.